# .NET User/server Control With Custom List Items

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I'm attempting to create a simple menu user control just as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794500/how-to-create-asp-net-user-server-control-that-uses-a-list-of-asplistitem-as-chi).

The attached code results in an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error, but I can't figure out why.  Any thoughts?

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MySite.master.vb" Inherits="MySite" %>
<%@ Register src="Controls/Menu.ascx" tagname="Menu" tagprefix="my"  %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>MySite</title>
    <link href="Styles/MySite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="headContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>    
</head>
<body id="masterBody" runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <my:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
            <MenuItems>
                <my:MenuItem Text="Test" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
            </MenuItems>
         </my:Menu>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Partial Class Controls_Menu
        Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Private m_Items As List(Of MenuItem) = Nothing
        <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _
        Public Property MenuItems() As List(Of MenuItem)
            Get
                Return m_Items
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As List(Of MenuItem))
                m_Items = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class

    Public Class MenuItem
        Private m_Text As String
        Public Property Text() As String
            Get
                Return m_Text
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)

            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_NavigateUrl As String
        Public Property NavigateUrl() As String
            Get
                Return m_NavigateUrl
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_NavigateUrl = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that here:

```
<MenuItems>
     <my:MenuItem Text="Test" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
</MenuItems>
```

ASP.net is trying to Add to your MenuItems list, it does this by calling

```
MenuItems.Add(...)
```

However, since m_Items is equal to Nothing, this gives you the error. To fix this replace

```
Private m_Items As List(Of MenuItem) = Nothing
```

With

```
Private m_Items As List(Of MenuItem) = New List(Of MenuItem)()
```

Comment: Are you displaying the MenuItem.Text? If so, you should change
    
    Private m_Text As String

To

    Private m_Text As String = ""

To avoid the null problem when displaying MenuItem.Text

If you are still getting the problem, can you post the full Error message including the stack trace?

Comment: My page is exactly as shown in the code -- I'm not displaying anything as of yet.  Error 2 Object reference not set to an instance of an object. C:\Websites\MySite\MySite.master 58

Comment: Please post the text for Menu.ascx

Comment: `<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Menu.ascx.vb" Inherits="Controls_Menu" %>
<asp:Table ID="menuTable" runat="server" CssClass="menu">
</asp:Table>`